# key compression in redis with python

Tags: python, redis

I have very large data set and I'm looking into using [Redis](http://redis.io/). My data set consists of: `sha1` hash and additional `n` value(s) that is associate with that hash.

I use my `sha1` hash as a key inside of `Redis` and my goal is to compress it somehow). I tried to use [zlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html) and then [base64](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html), but new hash is even longer then original `sha1` hash:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov 20 2015, 02:00:19) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.sha1('test').hexdigest()
'a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3'
>>> len(hashlib.sha1('test').hexdigest())
40
>>> import zlib
>>> len(zlib.compress(hashlib.sha1('test').hexdigest()))
46
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(hashlib.sha1('test').hexdigest()))
'eJwFwQkBACAIA8BKIihbHB7pH8G7oAXmnaoUZlwpqwXXVsojnNiT2foB7msLYg=='
>>> len(base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(hashlib.sha1('test').hexdigest())))
64
>>>
```

any ideas how to go about it?

---

I'm looking into following as well:

- [Redis memory-optimization](http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization)
- [How we cut down memory usage by 82% - Octivi Labs](http://labs.octivi.com/how-we-cut-down-memory-usage-by-82/)
- [Storing hundreds of millions of simple key-value pairs in Redis - Instagram Engineering](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/12202313862/storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value)

Answer (score 0):

Results of a hash function are more or less random data, so you can't really compress them. Depending on how may objects/hashes you're dealing with and how much you care about collisions, you could just use a part of the sha1 value if you want to save space or use an algorithm with a shorter digest size (md5, half of sha2-256). Also, you could not convert the digest from hex and use raw binary and save 50%. Finally, define "very large", it's very likely that the size of the key won't make a big difference.

Comment: Thank you for replying! In regards to collisions, `SHA1` is fine for me, unfortunately, I cannot use partial hash, and in terms of "very large" data set, in my case it's about 1B of hashes as of now.

Comment: How come no partial hash? Is it possible to describe your use case a bit more?

Comment: While I can definitely appreciate thinking "outside the box" approach) That makes me wonder, how many characters in that hash I could potentially loose, before introduce collisions ...

Comment: Quite a lot. 2^80 = 1208925819614629174706176. Your 1 billion objects will fit into that space 1208925819614629 times over ... :) If you're truely worried about collisions you need to deal with them anyway.